# Switch between turntable and trackball rotation

Tags: 3d-view

New to Blender.  Working exclusively in User Persp window on 3D viewport (which is how I always like to work in 3D Studio).

Looked everywhere, no info:  Where is the menu setting or key combo to lock the Z-axis so I can turntable my view orbits?

Comment: The only place I know is in the user preferences (CTrL ALT U), input >> orbit style (left column).

Answer (score 2):

Go to **User preferences**, then change the tab to ***Input*** then toggle the orbit style to your liking.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found solution with add-on: Toggle Orbit (BlenderMarket). Buttons added to the Header to toggle between Turntable and Trackball orbit method.